# angular 17 controlflow store in variable

Tags: angular, typescript

So most of us probably know the "store the conditional variable in a variable"-hack with `*ngIf="assertType(item) as renamedItem"` to assign a type to a variable

For me it was always pretty useful as in this example

```js
<ng-template
    gridCellTemplate
    let-item
>
    <ng-container *ngIf="assertType(item) as typedItem">
    ...
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

and

```js
    public assertType(item: any): ITEM_TYPE {
        return item;
    }
```

Is there a way to achieve this with the new [controlflow syntax](https://angular.dev/guide/templates/control-flow) `@if () {...}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your issue:

```
<ng-template
      gridCellTemplate
      let-item
    >
    @if (assertType(item); as typedItem) {
      <ng-container>
        ...
      </ng-container>
    }
</ng-template>
```

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ang5jv?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter) reference